# TPL Dataflow and Async Method Calls

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the whole concept of parallel processing and have set up test cases. After playing with the tests, I see that using Async method calls within Dataflow `ActionBlock` (or `TransformBlock`) does not positively affect performance, it just complicates the code. Am I right in assuming that if I'm using Dataflow Blocks, code within them does not have to be asynchronous, Dataflow will make it asynchronous by itself. Or am I missing the point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TPL Dataflow doesn't enable concurrency or parallelization (although you can get things like `ActionBlock` to parallelize its processing) it's something concurrent or parallel code uses to communicate data.  Among other things, it's a mechanism for message passing--which is kind of an alternative to shared data.  Shared data, when used by multiple threads requires expensive synchronization.  Message-passing, when done right, doesn't need synchronization because the data that needs to be worked on is encapsulated in a message that is "sent" to the code that will work on it.

TPL Dataflow is something you can use if you have a specific design.  If you are not specifically implementing something like [Actor-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model) programming, or [message-passing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_passing), or non-blocking producer/consumer scenarios, then TPL Dataflow will likely complicate things.

If you think that you might want to design a system like this, there's some good resources on understanding TPL Dataflow (TDF) like a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Stephen-Toub-Inside-TPL-Dataflow) by Stephen Toub (a member of the parallel team at Microsoft), as well as the [Dataflow MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603).

#### UPDATE:

You can set the maximum degree of parallelism for a block, but setting it higher than the number of CPUs or Cores is often counter-productive.  The assumption is that each action that executes is more-or-less CPU bound (using the CPU at 100% while it's running).  If the actions spend a lot of time waiting (waiting on a wait handle, waiting on messages in a message pump--which isn't normal for an action but is for a UI threa--etc.) then a degree of parallelism beyond the number of CPUs might make sense (although that would be hard to tweak).  When you *do* have more actions running than CPUs that *are* CPU bound you really start to task the OS.  The OS wants to give up CPU time to each thread (or each action in this case) because it's "running".  When there aren't enough CPUs to go around, the OS starts to preemptive multitask, round-robin giving CPU time to each active thread.  Each time the OS takes the CPU away from one thread and gives it to anther is called [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).  This is *really* expensive (in the range of [2000-8000 cpu cycles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163552.aspx#S4)).  So, the OS is really spending all its time context switching and not running your actions.

If your actions are really asynchronous then the degree of parallelism of the block is irrelevant because something else is doing the parallelising.  But, same issue arises, your asynchronous actions are being executed unchecked and you risk overwhelming the OS in the degree of context switching you introduce.  I would seriously consider *not* doing asynchronous actions because of this lack of control.

Comment: Yes, I'm designing a producer/consumer application with message passing. And I see that Dataflow is the best fit for this (compared to Tasks, ThreadPool etc.). But wanted to know would i still need Async methods within ActionBlocks.

Comment: You can set a level of parallelism with ActionBlock.  I believe it defaults to no parallelism (one block at a time, in order).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609.aspx for some details

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't ask my question clear enough. I do set DoP as unbounded (which from my understanding does not limit number of concurrent threads), but would also making code that executes inside the ActionBlock Async speed up processing, or would it be a waste

Comment: @Dimitri My response was much larger than a comment could be, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it does make a lot more sense.

Comment: I disagree that context switching is such a big problem in this case. Yes, setting the degree of parallelism to more than the number of cores won't make the program any faster, if the computation is CPU-bound. But TPL Dataflow uses ThreadPool by default, which means that each action doesn't get its own thread, most of the time. Instead, the actions are in a queue and the ThreadPool tries to use optimal number of threads to execute them.

Comment: @svick You might be thinking TPL and a ThreadPool scheduler.  ThreadPool defaults to 25 threads per cpu/core--more than enough to cause context-switching issues.  (`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem,` not TPL...)  But, if you tell the TPL that you want a maximum degree of parallelism you're telling it that everything should have its own thread (well, your asking for everything to run concurrently--currently the only way to do that is to give something its own thread).

Comment: @svick in fact, this is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963552.aspx

Comment: @PeterRitchie From the article you linked to: “In most cases, the built-in load balancing algorithms in the .NET Framework are the most effective way to manage these tradeoffs.” And TDF does use TPL, which in turn does use ThreadPool, which is why I am thinking about them. ThreadPool doesn't default to 25 threads per core, it starts with 1 thread per core, but this number can increase if the ThreadPool thinks this is appropriate (e.g. when one of the threads blocks).

Comment: @PeterRitchie And setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to unbounded doesn't mean that each item will be processed on its own thread, that would indeed be terribly inefficient. What it means is that it will use as many threads as the ThreadPool will let it, which will be around 1 per core most of the time.

Comment: @svick what they are saying is that the built-in load-balancing is most effective and that if you do change MDOP you're no longer using the built-in load balancing.  Otherwise the "Arbitrarily increasing the degree of parallelism puts you at risk of processor oversubscription" comment makes no sense.  It's pretty easy to show by simply using `Parallel.ForEach` with the `ParallelOptions` overload.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16392/discussion-between-svick-and-peter-ritchie)

Comment: @svick  Now, the ThreadPool is throttled by the intial number of threads it creates.  It only creates a new thread when needed once every second.  so, if it starts out with 5 thread and all your work can be down within a second, it will never use another thread because it has time to reuse some.  But, if you start action that take longer than a second or two, you'll see the thread pool create more threads, if MDOP is -1, that will be 25*CPU count (but will also take 25*CPU count seconds to get there...

Answer (score 1):

TPL Dataflow is not suitable for all kinds of parallel processing and it also won't make your code magically faster.

The main idea behind TDF is that you have blocks, which do their work independently. What this means is that the work for each block can be performed on a separate thread, so parallelizing your code using TDF can be very simple in some cases.

This can be especially useful if the code inside a block uses some resource that can't be shared. This way, you can get great utilization of that shared resource, because processing of this block is independent of other blocks.

In general, TDF is most suitable if your code is like a pipeline: an item comes in, gets processed by phase 1, then by phase 2, …, and finally it comes to the output. Although dataflow networks can be much more complicated than that. But you shouldn't try to force this, if what you want to do doesn't fit well with TDF, you're right that you will just complicate your code for no benefit.

Comment: Thanks svick for the input. My scenario is a perfect example of data pipeline where a piece of raw data goes through different stages of processing and is finally persisted to the database.